# Weird data issue in MySQL PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a query in PHP file as below. I get the data but its not complete. I have about 91 records in mysql but As soon as I add label column in query I just get about 80 record and when I add url column in query it get about 50 records.

I call it weird because as soon as I remove some content from Label columns in Database I get to see from 80 to 83 records.

```
$sql = "SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(title,'|', label,'|', id,'|', grp  SEPARATOR ';') prods FROM docLibrary3 GROUP BY title ";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

 $prods = explode(';',$row['prods']);
 echo '----'.$idx.'----<br>';

 foreach ($prods as $key => $value) {
   $expValue = explode('|',$value);
   echo $expValue[2].":: ".$expValue[3]."<br>";
 };

 $idx++;
};
```

Here how the out looks

```
----16----
58:: 08
59:: 09
60:: 11
61:: 12
62:: 15
63:: 02
64:: 1
65:: 13
57:: 07
56:: 06
48:: 02,11
49:: 01,12
50:: 12
51:: 01,12,15
52:: 013
53:: 02,11
54:: 01
:: 
----17----
75:: 01,02,07,08,11,12,13,15
74:: 02,07
73:: 09,10
72:: 11
71:: 02,06,08
70:: 01,02,11,12,13,15
69:: 01,02,11,12,13,16
68:: 01,02,11,12,13,15
67:: 01,02,11,12,13,15
66:: 01,02,11,12,13,15
----18----
85:: 01,02,11,12,13,15
86:: 01,02,11,12,13,15
87:: 01,02,11,12,15
88:: 03,04
89:: 03,04
90:: 01,06,07,08
84:: 01,02,11,12,13,15
83:: 01,02,11,12,15
82:: 01,02,11,12,13,15
::
```

55 and 91 record doesn't print but if I remove some content from label column from any record then some character shows in 55 and 91 record. First I though there may be some special character issue but then found that it was not. It become verse when I add url column in query.

Also not sure why record are not sorting by id column even when I add ORDER BY id in query.

UPDATED:
Here is the code that build nested array and print json - works fine but with missing data. I think something is going on in foreach loop or may be in data table

```
    $rows = array();
$idx = 0; 

  $sql = "SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(title,'|', label,'|', id,'|', grp,'|', url  SEPARATOR ';') prods FROM docLibrary3 GROUP BY title ";

  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
           $prods = explode(';',$row['prods']);
          foreach ($prods as $key => $value) {

            $expValue = explode('|',$value);
            echo $expValue[0].":: ".$expValue[3]."<br>";

            $rows[$idx]['title'] = $expValue[0];
            $rows[$idx]['subList'][] = array('label' => $expValue[1], 'url' => $expValue[2], 'grp' => $expValue[3]);

          };

          $idx++;
      };
  $siteData['list'] = $rows;
  var_export($rows, true);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($siteData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

UPDATE 2:
Trying to set group_concat_max_len but thats not working too

```
$sql = "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=3423543543"
  ."SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(title,'|', label,'|', id,'|', grp,'|', url  SEPARATOR ';') prods FROM docLibrary3 GROUP BY title ";
```

Comment: I think its because you are using group by.

Comment: Hmm, if I remove GROUP BY then its not even going in foreach loop

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve, as you don't appear to be using `title` or `label` in your code anywhere. I'd agree with @jophab in that using `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` is not the correct approach, but without a clearer picture of the goal, it's hard to provide more specific help without guessing.

Comment: Actually, I am building nested array and then printing json. I will update my post with that code too.

Comment: Look like I have to add group_concat_max_len. But its not working not sure if I am setting it right

$sql = "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=3423543543"
      ."SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(title,'|', label,'|', id,'|', grp,'|', url  SEPARATOR ';') prods FROM docLibrary3 GROUP BY title ";